# Can I make my for loop asynchronous with async functions?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a process which performs some sentiment analysis on a sentence. It needs a sentence input, a classier which is the sentiment analysis model we are using (https://huggingface.co/bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion?text=I+feel+a+bit+let+down) and returns a dictionary of results.

```py
def get_prediction(sentence: str, classifier: pipeline) -> dict:
    return classifier(sentence)
```

I want to apply this function to a list of sentences, so obviously I can do a for loop for this:

```py
results = []
for sentence in sentences:
   results.append(get_prediction(sentence, classifier))
```

But how can I do this asynchronously?

I have some code here to test this:

```py
import asyncio
import time
from transformers import pipeline


async def get_prediction(sentence: str, classifier: pipeline) -> dict:
    return classifier(sentence)


async def async_main(sentences: list, classifier: pipeline):
    tasks = [
        get_prediction(sentence, classifier) for sentence in sentences
    ]

    sentence_dict = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return sentence_dict


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_filepath = "filepath/to/data"
    sentences = get_sentences(data_filepath)

    logger.info(f"There are {len(sentences)} sentences")

    classifier = pipeline(
        "text-classification",
        model='bhadresh-savani/distilbert-base-uncased-emotion', 
        return_all_scores=True
    )

    logger.info("Starting sentiment analysis for normal method")
    main(sentences, classifier)

    logger.info("Starting sentiment analysis for async method")
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.run(async_main(sentences, classifier))
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)
```

This code however does not speed up the for loop, the two methods compute the results in a similar amount of time.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

I tried to implement this function to measure how fast the synchronous results performed compared to its asynchronous version, but this did not result in a speed up.

Comment: Asyncio can run another task while waiting for I/O. No slow I/O == no gain, just more overhead.

Comment: The classifier is probably CPU-bound, not I/O-bound. This means that `asyncio` and multithreading will have little effect on run time. Multiprocessing may improve run time, but this is highly dependent on the classifier implementation.